# QLPreviewView can not show the quicklook preview in sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, quicklook

I use **QLPreviewView** to show the quicklook preview in the app. Without sandbox, this works well, but once change the app to sandbox, the preview can not show up.

I found the error in Console: `QuickLookUIHelpe(20786) deny file-read-data XXX.`

I have used the **security-scoped bookmarks** & **com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write** to grant access the user home dir, then:

```
[allowedURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
self.myPreiviewItem.myURL = fileURL;
self.myQLPreviewView.previewItem = self.myPreiviewItem;
[self.myQLPreviewView refreshPreviewItem];
[allowedURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
```

with these, I can delete files of user home dir, but the QLPreviewView can not work.
I do not know what is the difference between these 2 scenes, does QLPreviewView need more for sandbox?

If I add **com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only** into the entitlement, the files in "Downloads" can be previewed, but other files of user home dir can not be previewed.

Comment: what's the difference between fileURL and allowedURL?

Comment: allowedURL just represents the granted dir by **com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write**, such as user home dir, while fileURL is a file to be previewed, and it is in the granted dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution!

`refreshPreviewItem` is an async call, so before Mac finishes loading the preview, the following api `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` immediately shutdown the access, as a result, Mac failed to load the preview successfully.

so the solution is: do **NOT** call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` here, keep the allowedURL's access right until you do not need the QL preview function, and then call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` there, such as when closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this, or at least a similar, issue a while back (in Mavericks).

This is why I started asking users for access to parent folders of files they wish to Quick Look. Feel free to look at how I do it in [this app of mine](https://codingturtle.com/chikoo), version 1.1 at the time of this writing. Just go into Chikoo → Preferences… → Folder Access. Here are two screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I confess that this is not a great solution. It’s a compromise that I came up with to work around the problem.

Comment: I also asked user for access to user home folder, still not work ~~